# Show a random image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am using the below code for generating random image from a bank of images in my assets folder of windows phone 8.1 app but it is throwing an exception though I have used the code in windows phone 8 app it worked perfectly.
What is wrong with the code though I have copied it from 
[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/e101e92b-b716-4c69-aa37-e7aff2057fda/sample-show-a-random-image-windowsphone?forum=wpdevelop)

```cs
List<string> pics = new List<string>()
{
"Assets/img1.png",
"Assets/img2.png",
"Assets/img3.png",
"Assets/zwp1.png",
"Assets/zwp2.png",
"Assets/zwp3.png",
"Assets/zwp4.png",
"Assets/zwp5.png"
};

Random rnd=new Random();

ImageBrush brush1 = new ImageBrush();
brush1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(pics[rnd.Next(0,7)],UriKind.Relative));
img1.Source = brush1.ImageSource;
```

Error is An exception of type `System.ArgumentException` occurred in `mscorlib.ni.dll` but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The given `System.Uri` cannot be converted into a `Windows.Foundation.Uri`. Please click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to provide absolute URI for your images in the `pics` list, using either ms-appx:/// or ms-appdata:/// and use `UriKind.Absolute` instead of `UriKind.Relative` in the Uri constructor.

See this [MSDN article for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.uri%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)